# British English use of the word 'continent' (mass of land)

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, language-evolution

I have a question regarding the use of the word ‘continent’ (as a mass of land) and thought someone here might be able to help.

I would like to clarify if it is correct to say that the UK, or Great Britain, is part of Europe – the continent, not the political union.

I understand that people on an island may refer to continental countries as ‘the continent’. It has been mentioned to me that over time, this phrasing became the norm and that now British people refer to the rest of Europe as continental Europe, or mainland Europe, as a way to separate themselves from the rest of the continent.

My view is that, though it might have become a common reference, the need to include the adjective ‘mainland’ or ‘continental’ reinforces the fact that the UK is a European country and that an adjective is to be added to the name of the continent to denote a different geographical situation to theirs.

Some definitions of the word ‘continent’ as a “main continuous expanse of land” can also confuse those who like to refer to the UK as a standalone when it comes to name continents.

I’ll formulate my question with an example. When talking about continents as destinations, if we say “This airline services all the countries in Europe”, is that commonly understood that the UK is also serviced by the airline? Or is there a need to specify “This airline services the UK and all of continental Europe”?

Thank you.
Al

Comment: If you, say, [look up Europe on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe), or search for any other map of that continent, it will include the UK. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The Brits think of their land as an island. Which it is. The rest of Europe, the mainland, they often refer to as "the continent. "

Comment: There is a frequent distinction in usage between "the continent of Europe" (which would include the UK and Ireland) and "continental Europe" (which would not). To confuse things, a headline in *The Times* from 22 October 1957 of "Heavy fog in the Channel, Continent cut off" demonstrates "the continent" can be a shorthand for "continental Europe" rather than "the continent of Europe".

Comment: The heading asks about the word "continent" but when we finally get to a question it asks about the usage of the word "Europe". This is contradictory. (It's common for a geographical term to refer to more than one thing, particularly with a distinction between specific and general, e.g. "city" for City of London vs Greater London; America for USA or the continent; different uses of the North, the Northeast, etc; mainland; Ireland; Britain vs Great Britain; different areas known locally as "town"; uses of up/down; ....)

Comment: It is not clear what the motivation for the question is. Have you ever seen *Europe* used in the way that excludes the UK (except when it is a shorthand for *European Union*, which is the usage you explicitly set aside)? As already pointed out by StuartF, the lengthy preamble about *continent* is not relevant to the question. (In the UK-centred contexts, *Continent* functions as a proper name, with a meaning distinct from that of *continent*, used as a common noun.)